# Some diverging issues of Word2Vec in Gensim using high alpha values

Tags: python-3.x, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

I am implementing word2vec in gensim, on a corpus with nested lists (collection of tokenized words in sentences of sentences form) with 408226 sentences (lists) and a total of 3150546 words or tokens.

I am getting a meaningful results (in terms of the similarity between two words using model.wv.similarity) with the  chosen values of 200 as size, window as 15, min_count as 5, iter as 10 and alpha as 0.5. All are lemmatized words and these all are input to models with vocabulary as 32716.

The results incurred from default alpha value, size, window and dimensions are meaningless for me based on the used data in computing the similarity values. However higher value of alpha as 0.5 gives me some meaningful results in terms of inducing meaningful similarity scores between two words. However, when I calculate the top n similar words, it's again meaningless. Does I need to change the entire parameters used in the initial training process.

I am still unable to reveal the exact reason, why the model behaves good with such a higher alpha value in computing the similarity between two words of the used corpus, whereas it's meaningless while computing the top n similar words with scores for an input word. Why is this the case?

Does it is diverging towards optimal solution. How to check this?

Any idea why is it the case is deeply appreciated.

Note: I'm using Python 3.7 on Windows machine with anaconda prompt and giving input to the model from a file.

This is what I have tried.

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore', category=UserWarning, module='gensim')
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
import ast

path = "F:/Folder/"
def load_data():
    global Sentences
    Sentences = []
    for file in ['data_d1.txt','data_d2.txt']:
        with open(path + file, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f1:
           Sentences.extend(ast.literal_eval(*f1.readlines()))
load_data()

def initialize_word_embedding():
    model = Word2Vec(Sentences, size = 200, window = 15, min_count = 5, iter = 10, workers = 4)
    print(model)
    print(len(model.wv.vocab))
    print(model.wv.similarity(w1 = 'structure', w2 = '_structure_'))
    similarities = model.wv.most_similar('system')
    for word, score in similarities:
        print(word , score)

initialize_word_embedding()
```

The example of Sentences list is as follows:

> [['*scientist*', '*time*', '*comet*', '*activity*', '*sublimation*', '*carbon*', '*dioxide*', '*nears*', '*ice*', '*system*'], ['*inconsistent*', '*age*', '*system*', '*year*', '*size*', '*collision*'], ['intelligence', 'system'], ['example', 'application', 'filter', 'image', 'motion', 'channel', 'estimation', 'equalization', 'example', 'application', 'filter', 'system']]

The `data_d1.txt` and `data_d2.txt` is a nested list (list of lists of lemmatized tokenized words). I have preprocessed the raw data and save it in a file. Now giving the same as input. For computing the lemmatizing tokens, I have used the popular WordNet lemmatizer.

I need the word-embedding model to calculate the similarity between two words and computing the most_similar words of a given input word. I am getting some meaningful scores for the `model.wv.similarity()` method, whereas in calculating the `most_similar()` words of a word (say, `system` as shown in above). I am not getting the desired results.

I am guessing the model is getting diverged from the global minima, with the use of high alpha values.

I am confused what should be the dimension size, window for inducing some meaningful results, as there is no such rules regarding how to compute the the size and window.

Any suggestion is appreciated. The size of total sentences and words are specified above in the question.

Results what I am getting without setting alpha = 0.5

> Edit to Recent Comment:

Results:

> Word2Vec(vocab=32716, size=200, alpha=0.025)

The similarity between `set` and `_set_` is : `0.000269373188960656`
which is meaningless for me as it is very very less in terms of accuracy, But, I am a getting 71% by setting alpha as 0.5, which seems to be meaningful for me as the word `set` is same for both the domains.

Explanation: The word `set` should be same for both the domains (as I am comparing the data of two domains with same word). Don't get confused with word `_set_`, this is because the word is same as set, I have injected a character `_` at start and end to distinguish the same for two different domains.

The top 10 words along with scores of `_set_` are:

```
_niche_ 0.6891741752624512
_intermediate_ 0.6883598566055298
_interpretation_ 0.6813371181488037
_printer_ 0.675414502620697
_finer_ 0.6625382900238037
_pertinent_ 0.6620787382125854
_respective_ 0.6619025468826294
_converse_ 0.6610435247421265
_developed_ 0.659270167350769
_tent_ 0.6588765382766724
```

Whereas, the top 10 words for set are:

```
cardinality 0.633270263671875
typereduction 0.6233855485916138
zdzisław 0.619156002998352
crisp 0.6165326833724976
equivalenceclass 0.605925977230072
pawlak 0.6058803200721741
straight 0.6045454740524292
culik 0.6040038466453552
rin 0.6038737297058105
multisets 0.6035065650939941
```

Why the `cosine similarity value` is 0.00 for the word `set` for two different data.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185525/discussion-on-question-by-m-s-some-diverging-issues-of-word2vec-in-gensim-using).

Comment: Not interested in hiding shared knowledge off in some side chat that's hard to find and might disappear.  @M_S, please extend your question with further details/queries, or if you have a new distinct question, ask it separately. But my main points are: (1) don't even touch `alpha` until things are generally working; (2) explain further why you've got this atypical `set` vs `_set_` dichotomy, and whether the two variants of words ever appear together in shared contexts (the only way their vectors could achieve meaningful relative distances).

Comment: Sure. I will extend it, after performing some more experiments. By the way, I'm always grateful to you, with your productive, crystal clear, helpful discussions and suggestions.